# How to set a EditText in a certain column of a TableLayout?

Tags: android, tablelayout, editbox

I have a `TableLayout` on one Android Activity UI. It has two columns. 
Now I need to add a new row, and put an `EditText` box in second column of that new row. And also, I want that `EditText` to fill the whole cell. I have some code like this:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(context);
EditText et = new EditText(context);
et.SetMaxLines(4);
etText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));  //set it to the second coloumn

tr.addView(et);

tl.addView(tr);   //tl is the tableLayout
```

It puts the `EditText` in the second column fine, but the `EditText` is too small. I tried to use

```
etText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

but that seems to disabled the `TableRow.LayoutParams` setting. I guess each control can only have one `LayoutParams` setting.

So, how to make the EditText as a 4 lines text editor and also make sure it is in the second column of that row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

TableRow.LayoutParams params = TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

params.column = 1;

etText.setLayoutParams(params);

Answer (score 0):

This is for monodroid, but you should be able to convert for java

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
var param = new TableRow.LayoutParams(1);
et.LayoutParameters = param;
```

Just change 1 to whatever column of your table you want the edittext to show up in.